# Host multiple Rack apps on one server with multiple ports (using Apache and Passenger)

Tags: apache-2.2, ruby-on-rails, phusion-passenger, ruby, ruby-rack

I've search online and been reading documentation for Apache, Passenger, Rack, etc, but have yet to find a solution to my problem.

I have several Rack (ruby)-based apps, located in

```
/home/web/sites/app1
/home/web/sites/app2
/home/web/sites/app3
```

app1 is a Sintra app, app2 is Padrino and app3 is Rails.

I would like to run these apps under different ports (assuming server IP is 50.60.70.101):

```
50.60.70.101:4567 -> app1
50.60.70.101:3000 -> app2
50.60.70.101:80   -> app3
```

What is the correct way to configure Apache's virtual host file to achieve this?

I have 3 files in /etc/apache2/sites-available/ with this type of configuration (with changed IPs):

```
<VirtualHost *:4567>
    RackEnv         production

    DocumentRoot    /home/web/sites/app1/public
    <Directory      /home/web/sites/app1/public>
        Order   allow,deny
        Allow   from all
        Options -MultiViews
        #AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

But I cannot access app1 at 50.60.70.101:4567 (app3 does work on port 80, though).

Comment: I'm assuming you mean port when you say IP as you haven't mentioned an IP other than 50.60.70.101.  What error do you receive when accessing Apache on either of the higher ports? 50.60.70.101:4567 and 50.60.70.101:3000

Comment: That's correct, I stated that I want to run these apps under different ports with the same IP address. Accessing the ports in the browser, or pinging them times outs.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to explicitly tell Apache to listen on those ports with the `Listen` directive; have a look at [Binding to Addresses and Ports](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/bind.html).

Comment: /etc/apache2/ports.conf contains the following directives:

`NameVirtualHost *:80`
`NameVirtualHost *:3000`
`NameVirtualHost *:4567`

`Listen 80`
`Listen 3000`
`Listen 4567`



Relevant output for netstat -tulpn:

`tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -`
`tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -`
`tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -`
`tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4567            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -`